# MS Access data base reading in c# .exe project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access-2007, setup-project

I have created .EXE setup of C# Data Base (MS Access Data Base) Application using this link [Create C# Setup](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/436052/including-a-ms-access-database-file-in-executable). Actually i have only one windows form in my project where i can INSERT and GET the data from MS Access data base.It retrieves data from data base successful, But when i INSERT some data then prompt error message is displayed,that U can only update the Data Base and can't INSERT new data. I don't know what i have done wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i got my problem. Actually i had installed my project in drive C:\Program File... which i have made Secure, and no deletion or Insertion in a file inside there can occur. So, what i did, is that i reinstall that new software in other Drive, like D:\ and new it is working well.